# elasticsearch query with R

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I have me request in ES:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "event_type": "items_at_hero_level"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": { 
                "device_id": "%s"   <-first parameter
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "event_time": {
            "lte": "%d"   <- second parameter
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have 2 vectors:

1. with device_id's
2. with dates

I need to create a loop with R(elastic package) of this query with all device_id's and dates.

I know how it works with one parameter:

```
aggs<-'{
"size": 1, 
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
 {"term": {"event_type": "AppFirstStart"}},
 {"term": {"device_id": "%s"}}
]
}
},
"sort": [
   {
"event_time": {
 "order": "asc"
 }
 }
 ]
 }'
 for (i in seq_along(userIds)) 
 {
   AppFirstStart <- Search(index = "game_events_337", body = sprintf(aggs,   userIds[i]), 
asdf = TRUE)
 }
```

But i need to loop two.

Comment: you haven't shown any code you've come up with/tried at all.

Comment: aggs<-'{
    "size": 1, 
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{"term": {"event_type": "AppFirstStart"}},
{"term": {"device_id": "%s"}}
]
}
},
"sort": [
       {
"event_time": {
"order": "asc"
}
}
]
}'
for (i in seq_along(userIds)) 
{
  AppFirstStart <- Search(index = "game_events_337", body = sprintf(aggs, userIds[i]), asdf = TRUE)

Comment: Sorry how can I create useful code here?

Comment: add it to the question.

Comment: smasell Did you figure this out? i'm the `elastic` maintainer if you need any help. Opening an issue at the repo github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues may be faster as well